# Intellisense comment on a object variable in VS2012

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, visual-studio-2012, comments

I'm trying to create intellisense (VS2012) comments in my javascript code. I'm using class constructions and want to add comments to a class variable (the self.name in this example)

```
bht.ProcessStep = function (data, instrument) {
   var self = this;
   self.name = "test";
};
```

I tried to comment this as a `<field>`, but that won't work. The only solution I found to make it work is to add the following comment as a seperate line in the class (so not directly above the "name" declaration).

```
/// <field name='name' static='false' type='String'>Name of the process step.</field>
```

Is there a way to add this comment directly above my declaration?

Answer (score 0):

This page indicates you could define your intellisense is as the first line of the method definition, or you could use a completely seperate file

*Create an XML file that has documentation comments in the OpenAjax MessageBundle format.*

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514138.aspx